# How to get data from API use url and key javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have API key and I want fetch data, I have function to get data, but I get **undefined** value.

My code:

```
let url = "https://baza-gai.com.ua/nomer/KA0007XB";
let key = "2da3036efb196e460f0de7c55aa7295b";
let request = fetch(url, {headers: {"Accept": "application/json", "X-Api-Key": key}}).then(r => r.json());

let data; request.then(d => data = d);

console.log(data)
```

How I can get JSON from this url, and key?

Comment: You are logging the value before it's set, the `then` hasn't executed yet.

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` executed before request completion. Try this one:

```
let data; request.then(d => {data = d; console.log(data)});
```